# share global variable with batch process in matlab

Tags: matlab, global-variables, share, batch-processing

i have a variable `t=toc;` in a MATLAB function. `t` changes the value in loop. currently the function is running as batch process in matlab. i want to read `t` from calling function. I tried declairing `t` as a global variable which can be accessed by all functions. but it is not working in case of batch process. can anyone suggest what to do?

Comment: what do you mean by "batch process" ?

Comment: matlab provides a function in PCT `batch('script')` which i used to run a function as batch process. hope this will clarify any doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a batch process is executed on a matlab worker (a separate process). This worker is unable to perform any other action as m-code is single threaded. You can't read variables from a batch process which is not finished.

As a possible workaround you can write the information you need into a file and read it in your primary matlab instance.

Comment: Actually i am using `imfreehand()` to mark a region. A function named `timestamp()` (this is written by me) which performs a timing operation is running. when i use `imfreehand`, while marking `timestamp()` stops and starts again when marking is done. but i want to run both marking and timing operations to gather. how to do it?

Comment: @samran: From your comment I don't understand what you are trying to implement. I recommend to ask a new question where you explain what you are trying to implement. If possible provide short example code which explains your problem.